# Vuetify v-radio label got broken after using label slot once

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**Context:**

I've decided to create a v-radio button with v-text-field as a label for it.

I used the label slot like this:

```
<v-radio
  v-for="option in question.options"
  :key="option"
  :label="option"
  :value="option"
>
  <template #label>
    <v-text-field
    label="Test"
    />
  </template>
</v-radio>
```

**Problem:**

This is the output that I got when applying the previous code snippet:

[image]

**Additional Info:**

I checked another normal radio button in the project
(which is copied from Vuetify docs)

The code is as follows:

```
<v-radio
  label="red darken-3"
  color="red darken-3"
  value="red darken-3"
/>
```

Here is the output for that code:

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to get a normal radio button with input text without having two radio button "circles"?

Vuetify version: `^2.4.5`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but you are wrapping your whole code correctly in a `<v-app>`, aren't you?

Comment: yeah, sure I have a complete layout. and everything else is working very fine.

Comment: That's pretty odd. You might have added some weird styles or the radio button is broken for the given Vuetify version. Try up-/downgrading the version.

Comment: It's really odd. I haven't even used any style tag. I've run `npm update vuetify -D` previously

Comment: can you recreate it in a fiddle, I wasn't able with vuetify 2.4.5, seems ok, check the classes attached to the radio element

Comment: you're not going to believe how it worked finally. After getting a very deep breath. I thought about checking if the same thing would happen for a checkbox. So, I added a `v-chcekbox` above it. and out of the blue, all `v-radio` tags were fixed.
@Aer0 @Daniel

Comment: but it's still occurring, ps: I'm using Laravel Mix with hot reload

Comment: Just figured something:
when it's working fine there is a style that's enabled `.v-input--selection-controls__input input[role=checkbox], .v-input--selection-controls__input input[role=radio], .v-input--selection-controls__input input[role=switch]` but when it's broken this selector doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got it fixed after digging for hours I realized that I have tree-shaking enabled in my `Vuetify`. I mean I was importing `Vuetify` like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify()
```

I changed it back to

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify()
```

after that, it worked always as expected. I still don't know how to get it fixed with tree-shaking enabled.